# Optimise WHERE IN query

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables. Both contain shared data.

```sql
CREATE TABLE 'data' (
    HashCode INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    OtherColumns INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE 'datahash' (
    PrimaryKey INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    HashCode INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (HashCode) REFERENCES 'data' (HashCode) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

This is all and well. Data is added to the `data` table and then to `datahash`, linking their `HashCode` columns. If the `HashCode` is deleted from `data`, it'll cascade to delete `datahash` rows.

I want to now select from a list of `PrimaryKey` their matching `data` data. I do this with:

```sql
SELECT 'datahash'.PrimaryKey, 'data'.* FROM 'data'
    JOIN 'datahash' ON 'datahash'.PrimaryKey IN (SELECT PrimaryKey FROM 'templist') AND 'datahash'.HashCode = 'data'.HashCode
    LIMIT 1000000;
```

The mentioned `templist` is a `TEMP TABLE` in memory:

```sql
PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY;
CREATE TEMP TABLE 'templist' (
    PrimaryKey INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);
```

This temporary table exists as it's hard in code to do `SELECT ... JOIN 'keyhash' ON 'datahash'.PrimaryKey IN (?, ?, ?...)...` where the `IN` list can have a dynamic number of values.

The problem is that the `SELECT` with the join is noticeably slow.

From a explain query plan:

| id | parent | notused | detail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | SEARCH datahash USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) |
| 7 | 0 | 0 | USING ROWID SEARCH ON TABLE test FOR IN-OPERATOR |
| 12 | 0 | 0 | SEARCH data USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) |

In time terms:

- inserting takes ~110ms for 100k rows into `templist`
- select join query then takes ~420ms to return matching rows in a 1 million rows of both 'data' and 'datahash'

What can I do to improve the performance?
I'm already inserting and selecting in a single transaction.

Comment: Apologies. Thanks for pointing that out. It's been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a JOIN between keyhash and templist.

```
SELECT keyhash.PrimaryKey, data.*
FROM templist 
JOIN keyhash ON keyhash.PrimaryKey = templist.PrimaryKey
JOIN data ON keyhash.HashCode = data.HashCode
LIMIT 1000000;
```

You should get a query plan like this:

| id | parent | notused | detail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | SCAN templist |
| 7 | 0 | 0 | SEARCH keyhash USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) |
| 10 | 0 | 0 | SEARCH data USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) |

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it seems that this does not improve the speed when selecting.

Comment: @AsdTulip To be honest, 420 ms to extract 100k records is actually pretty fast. And you are already using the equivalent of clustered indexes. I don't think it could become faster than that. You can only try with more memory/cache.